# How to split up a column with 2D array, based on index Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My current data frame is this.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|scores                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[1000, 1234, 4.6789], [2000, 1234, 4.0], [3000, 1234, 3.6789], [4000, 1234, 2.6789]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to convert it to the one below where the columns are separated the their index in the 2d scores array.

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|score 1              |score2               |score3                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|[1000,2000,3000,4000]|[1234,1234,1234,1234]|[4.6789,4.0,3.6789,2.6789] |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the community. Could you please share whatever you have tried.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm just a little confused on how to approach this. One of the ways I was thinking was just too iterate row by row and split it up manually, but is there an easier more Scala way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have broken down the required steps below.

First of all, I recreated your data as follows:

```
val scores = spark.read.json(Seq("""{"scores": [[1000, 1234, 4.6789], [2000, 1234, 4.0], [3000, 1234, 3.6789], [4000, 1234, 2.6789]]}""").toDS)

scores.select(explode($"scores").alias("scores")).show(false)

+------------------------+
|scores                  |
+------------------------+
|[1000.0, 1234.0, 4.6789]|
|[2000.0, 1234.0, 4.0]   |
|[3000.0, 1234.0, 3.6789]|
|[4000.0, 1234.0, 2.6789]|
+------------------------+
```

The next step splits each element in each array to a column

```
val split = scores.select(explode($"scores")).select((0 until 3).map(i => col("col")(i).alias(s"col$i")): _*)

split.show

+------+------+------+
|  col0|  col1|  col2|
+------+------+------+
|1000.0|1234.0|4.6789|
|2000.0|1234.0|   4.0|
|3000.0|1234.0|3.6789|
|4000.0|1234.0|2.6789|
+------+------+------+
```

Then, we collect the rows in each column into a sequence

```
val res = (0 to 2).map(i => split.select(s"col$i").collect.map(_.getDouble(0))).toDS

res.show

+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[1000.0, 2000.0, ...|
|[1234.0, 1234.0, ...|
|[4.6789, 4.0, 3.6...|
+--------------------+
```

Finally, we transpose the data into the format you requested

```
val scoresFinal = res.agg(collect_list("value").alias("result")).select((0 until 3).map(i => col("result")(i).alias(s"score${i+1}")): _*)

scoresFinal.show

+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|              score1|              score2|              score3|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[1000.0, 2000.0, ...|[1234.0, 1234.0, ...|[4.6789, 4.0, 3.6...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I am looking to get score1 as the first element of every sub array so [1000,2000,3000,4000] and score2 as the second element in every subarray [1234,1234,1234,1234] and score three as the third element in every sub array [4.6789,4.0,3.6789,2.6789] . Does this make sense, I know how to separate based on the whole subarray, but I am looking to organize them in a way as seen above. Thank you